# Cucumber Junit Selenide with spring parallel tests

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber-junit, selenide, parallel-tests

can somebody help with this problem? i have cucumber junit with selenide and spring boot, and i want to execute my tests in parallel, but it does not work. my pom file is this and may i have some problem here?

```
 ` <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>ge.smartsource</groupId>
<artifactId>smart-source-java</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <selenium.version>4.2.1</selenium.version>
    <webdrivermanager.version>5.2.0</webdrivermanager.version>
    <testng.version>7.6.0</testng.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.7</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.13.6</allure.version>
    <cucumber.version>6.10.4</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- cucumber users only -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- allure users only -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- testng users only -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserup</groupId>
        <artifactId>browserup-proxy-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codepine.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>testrail-api-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber6-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>all</parallel>
                <threadCount>3</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`
```

also my junit runner class it this, may there need some additional information for run parallel tests

```
   ` @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SpillenbodenApplication.class,
        SpillRegistrationRegressionTest.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:features"},
        glue = {"com.example.spillenboden.pageSteps"},
        tags = "@login",
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.html",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json",
                "io.qameta.allure.cucumber6jvm.AllureCucumber6Jvm"
        }`
```

Comment: I see both JUnit 5 and TestNG. And I see that JUnit 4 (Vintage) is excluded. However you are running your tests with JUnit 4. You may want to start with a smaller project to see if you can get parallel execution work in general before adding more complications. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example